# Disable zsh autocorrect entirely

Tags: zsh

How do you disable zsh autocorrect entirely?

I am aware of the 'nocorrect' option which only applies to certain commands.  But I want it off entirely so that when I type 'lear' instead of 'clear', it won't prompt for a correction.

I should note that 'unsetopt correctall' doesn't seem to do anything for me

```
collin@mandalay ~
  % unsetopt correctall

collin@mandalay ~
  % lear
zsh: correct 'lear' to 'clear' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: lear
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ahhhh!!... I see that I was supposed to use 'unsetopt correct' instead of correct_all

```
collin@mandalay ~
  % unsetopt correct

collin@mandalay ~
  % lear
zsh: command not found: lear
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me on Manjaro.

Answer (score 10):

In your .zshrc file:

```
 #disable auto correct
 unsetopt correct_all
```

From the manpage of zsh (zshoptions):

```
   CORRECT (-0)
          Try to correct the spelling of commands.  Note that, when the HASH_LIST_ALL option is not set or when some directories in the  path  are  not readable, this may falsely report spelling errors the first time some commands are used.

   CORRECT_ALL (-O)
          Try to correct the spelling of all arguments in a line.
```

So the **correct** option will correct ONLY the commands not the arguments on the line.

The **correct_all** option will correct commands AND all the arguments on the line.

Comment: This is incorrect.  correct_all will disable autocorrect for options only, not for commands themselves.  See here for an example: http://yountlabs.com/automation/disable-autocorrect-in-zsh/

Comment: I improved my answer (forgot to login while editing it).

Comment: That isn't how it works for me. I am using zsh 4.3.17. See my initial post. 'unsetopt correctall' (correct_all and correctall are equivalent) then typing 'lear' instead of 'clear' results in the auto-correct prompt.  Seems the name 'correct_**all**'is misleading. Based on the description it says "Try to correct the spelling of all **arguments** in a line'

Comment: @Collin, load order matters. It worked for me when I moved it to bottom, after oh-my-zsh

Comment: I can confirm @CollinPeters experience. `unsetopt correct_all`, even as the last thing on the zshrc, doesn't get rid of that correction prompt. `unsetopt correct` does.

Answer (score 9):

Only putting the following lines in `.zshrc` **does not work for me.**

```
unsetopt correct_all
unsetopt correct
```

It **works** after I commented out this line :

```
ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"
```

Hopes it work for you as well.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you cannot modify your .zshrc or .zhsenv (I speak about the .zhsenv because some answers external to this post talk about modifying this file, although seeing the default comments in files it seems that .zshrc is the right one) :

you can modify your .zshrc.user . I put in it :

```
#Disable autocorrect
unsetopt correct_all
unsetopt correct
DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"
```

This is probably redundant (the last line)

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you happen to be using the grml configuration (and have somehow forgotten): add the following line to your .zshrc.pre or .zshrc.local:

> NOCOR=1

The normal method is, as mentioned by others, to use a `unsetopt correct_all` and/or `unsetopt correct` - but this is overridden by the grml config.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS Monterey with zsh 5.8.1, commenting

```
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"
unsetopt correct_all
unsetopt correct
```

did not change the behaviour. Only worked when setting it to False explicitly:

```
ENABLE_CORRECTION="false"
unsetopt correct_all
unsetopt correct
```

Also, do not forget to source file afterwards
`source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

There's a variable ENABLE_CORRECTION in ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/correction.zsh.

What helped me was setting this variable to "false" (or anything != "true") *before* sourcing "oh-my-zsh" in ~/.zshrc:

```
export ENABLE_CORRECTION="false"
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Also - many answers here recommend to set ENABLE_CORRECTION or DISABLE_CORRECTION without "export". That wouldn't work. Variable must be exported in order for other shell scripts to "see" it unless it's used in the same script only.